# MSVS2010 Coded UI Tests no longer work when saving/generating methods

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

The coded UI test functionality used to work, but now it won't allow any methods to be saved. I keep seeing the following error: "The code could not be generated because the cursor in the source code file is not located within a method.  Place the cursor in the method where you want to insert the generated code."

I receive this error when:

- I create a new coded UI test and try to save a method.
- I right click within a previously recorded coded UI test and try to save the new method’s actions.
- I create a new project and create a new coded UI test and then try to save a method

Restarting both Visual Studio and Windows 7 (x64) have no effect in fixing the problem.

This happens on both existing projects and new ones.  What do I need to do fix repair VS?

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify [CodedUITest] Attribute for your class and [TestMethod] for your test method?
Generation is available only when having cursor in the test method.